# Scatter plot ggplot2 not showing all values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Why is it that when I make a scatterplot in R using ggplot2, it does not produce all the points? In this plot, there should be about 500 points, yet it probably doesn't even have 100?

I know that missing values are automatically removed: it tells me how many it removed, and I have accounted for that. The code i use is

```
ggplot(data, aes( x = Longitude,  y = Latitude)) + geom_jitter()
```

Comment: try changing alpha to check how many values in same place

Comment: When you change alpha, some are more visible than others. Does this mean that those that are more visible represent more points? That lie on top of each other?

Comment: Right! the lightest have only one point, the darkest may have hundreds...

Comment: Well that solves it then. THX.

Comment: alpha is a transparency feature, so you make a dot transparent and you can see overlap as layers of transparency build up...